# setonclicklistener on another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, listener

Say I have two activities: "A" and "B".

Activity A has a button in it's layout. and I want to set it's click listener implemention on Activity B.
So let's say here's Activity A:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(B.this);
```

and in Activity B, I'm trying to implement the function:

```
public void OnClick(View v)
{
//DO SOMETHING
}
```

I'm getting the following errors:

> The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View
>   is not applicable for the arguments (A)
>
> - No enclosing instance of the type A is accessible in scope

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The handling of the GUI components must be accompanied within the same UI thread that instantiated that.

**So your desired view is not correct** also make sure the you can have the click and other listener been worked only if the view is set with that components and is currently visible ( In foreground) for the user to have interaction.

If you really want that then You can override the default implementation of the click listener within the different activities via following:

1)**Static Reference**: make the button as public static in activity A and use it in Activity B by Class A's name.

2)**Interface**:implements OnClickListener on the activity A , but will not be accessible in B

3)**Custom MyClickListener** for all activites.

```
public class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mContext = v.getContext();

        switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.button:
// Your click even code for all activities
break;
default:
break; }}
}
```

Use it the class A and B both as shown below:
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm really in a rush, I read only the first senteces of your questions. The actual situation is that I have a listview activity and custom adapter activity, the custom adapter has a Button, I want that the listview "will know" when a click event has occured from the adapter activity, so I can have a reference to objects that exist only on the listview that's what I'm trying to do. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there any simple answer due to my explanatipm?

Comment: to be more simple and clear.. you can have click event for the button in getView of adpater

Comment: also listView has the methids getChildAt(child position) and you can grad the view inflated and even do manupulations from other than that getview methods

Comment: I'm aware of that I can create a click event in the adapter but then I will not have a reference to the wanted object that exist in the listview activity

Comment: I don't really understand how the getchildat method can help me here, I need to determine when the user presses on the button. I tried to implement the OnListItemClick but it doesn't get called when I click the button for some reason.. Uh, there's not really another alternative?

Comment: Read more buddy ... http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.in/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html

Comment: Oh wow that's great, I'll be trying to implement it on my own project and let you know what's going, thank you!

Comment: I just didn't understand what's the first XML code there belongs to? Is it the adapter XML?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16794/discussion-between-arpit-garg-and-idish)

Comment: Hmm. I sent you messages in the chat, I don't know if you get notified from the messages in the chat, so I'm posting a comment here. BTW, if you saw my messages and you can not help me any longer I'll still be very thankfull for your help and giving me a clue of what I should do, just let me know please if you're going to help me any further or I should just keep in my project, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass an instance of an OnClickListener to `button.setOnClickListener(..)`.  Class A isn't implementing OnClickListener, so you must implement it in order for it to be an instance of an OnClickListener.

```
class A extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    // instance variable, constructors, etc
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) { // note onClick begins with lowercase
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
}
```

Comment: Alright, now I'm getting only one error: No enclosing instance of the type Categories is accessible in scope

Comment: That error is unrelated and is another question altogether, sorry.