# Attempt to invoke virtual method View.SetOnClickListener on a null object reference in Android

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm currently in the process of refining an app I made a year ago where everything was handled in the main activity class. I'm trying to make it more modular so that I can change minute details here and there and so on. However, whenever I try to set my onClickListener for a set of buttons, I get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

The basic set-up of my activity is a button that says "start" and whenever you click it, it goes invisible and then 15 other buttons become visible. 
I made a custom onClickListener that I simply named ClickListener that looks like this:

```
public class ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    Activity a;
    Context c;
    ButtonChanger bc;

    public ClickListener(Activity a, Context c, ButtonChanger bc) {

        this.a = a;
        this.c = c;
        this.bc = bc;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {

            case R.id.start_button:

                bc.toggleButtons();

                break;

            default:

                break;

        }

    }

}
```

For reference, here's a part of my ButtonChanger class:

```
public class ButtonChanger {

    public Buttons buttons;
    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;

    public ButtonChanger(Activity activity, Context context) {

        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = context;
        this.buttons = new Buttons();

    }

    public void toggleButtons() {

        // unimportant to issue... basically toggles visibility of buttons

    }

}
```

My Buttons class is basically just used for storing an array of MyButton objects in the example and my MyButton class basically just stores the id of the correlating button view. (They have a lot of other functions outside of this issue)

Here's where I attempt to set the onClickListener in my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ButtonChanger bc;
    ClickListener cl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        bc = new ButtonChanger(this, this);
        cl = new ClickListener(this, this, bc);

        Button but;
        for(MyButton b : bc.buttons.buttons) {
            but = (Button)findViewById(b.getId());
            but.setOnClickListener(cl);
        }

        Button start =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_button);
        start.setOnClickListener(cl);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

}
```

The error points to the lines where I do but.setOnClickListener(...), even the one where I just flat-out use the R.id.start_button. So, it isn't an issue of the id not being properly saved in the MyButton object. I believe it has to do with my custom ClickListener but I'm not sure what. I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12464857/setonclicklistener-on-another-activity) as reference whenever I made my ClickListener class.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're trying to find your `Button`s before they're there. You need to call `setContentView()` before the `findViewById()` calls.

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you, this fixed it!